# object reference not executing function inside arduino function call

Tags: http, arduino, header, client

I have an object which I define in void loop() as `WiFiClient client = server.available()`

I try to pass the client inside my loop() to my function call `checkHeader(&client)`

However when I try to call the client to print out data, the client simply hangs and prints nothing out

```
void checkHeader(WiFiClient *theclient){
 if (header.indexOf("GET /controller") > -1) {
     int startPos = header.indexOf("GET /controller");
     int endPos = header.indexOf(" HTTP/1.1");
     startPos += 15;
     //String toPrint = header.substring(startPos, endPos);
     Serial.println("LETS PRINT THE PARAM VALUE");
     Serial.println(name);
     theclient->println(name); //doesn't print anything
  }
 else if(header.indexOf("GET /reset") > -1){
     int startPos = header.indexOf("GET /controller");
     int endPos = header.indexOf(" HTTP/1.1");
     startPos += 10;
     //String toPrint = header.substring(startPos, endPos);
     Serial.print("reset the controller");
     theclient->println("controller is being reset"); //doesn't print anything
     reboot();
  }
}
```

however inside my void loop(), simply using `client.println("something to print")` works fine.
I'm not sure where I am messing up here or perhaps i'm fumbling around too much with the http request/response pattern in doing this?

Hoping someone might have some insight that will help me out

Here is my current full code for reference

```
/*

 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>


#include "arduino_secrets.h" 
///////please enter your sensitive data in the Secret tab/arduino_secrets.h
char ssid[] = SECRET_SSID;        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = SECRET_PASS;    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;
String name = "controller02";
// your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

WiFiServer server(80);
String header;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the WiFi module:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv < "1.0.0") {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  server.begin();
  // you're connected now, so print out the status:
  printWifiStatus();
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.write(c);
        header += c;
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          // send a standard http response header
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
          client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
          client.println();

          //check the header to see which command the controller has been given
          checkHeader(&client);
         
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");
          
          // run the checks here to analyze the routes
          
          client.println("</html>");
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);

    // close the connection:
    header = "";
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disonnected");
  }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}

void checkHeader(WiFiClient *theclient){
 if (header.indexOf("GET /controller") > -1) {
     int startPos = header.indexOf("GET /controller");
     int endPos = header.indexOf(" HTTP/1.1");
     startPos += 15;
     //String toPrint = header.substring(startPos, endPos);
     Serial.println("LETS PRINT THE PARAM VALUE");
     Serial.println(name);
     theclient->println(name);
  }
 else if(header.indexOf("GET /reset") > -1){
     int startPos = header.indexOf("GET /controller");
     int endPos = header.indexOf(" HTTP/1.1");
     startPos += 10;
     //String toPrint = header.substring(startPos, endPos);
     Serial.print("reset the controller");
     theclient->println("controller is being reset");
     reboot();
  }
}

void reboot() {
  wdt_disable();
  wdt_enable(WDTO_15MS);
  while (1) {}
}
```

Comment: In the line just before the `reboot` call, the code differs from the first block to the second block of code. In the first you call `theclient->println` and in the second `theclient->write`.

Comment: @HugoCunha oops my apologies, I'd left that in there from a previous attempt, I am now using client.println() in both sections but unfortunately having the same result